# What is the name for the "main" root of a number? (The one we get through exponentiation)

Tags: complex-numbers, definition, roots

The $n$-th root of a number has $n$ answers (or return values), however, only one can be obtained by replacing the root with exponentiation. Is there a name for such "main" root?

$$\sqrt[n]{a} = (a)^{1/n}$$

Example: The cubic roots of $-8$ are $-2$, $2e^{iπ/3}$ and $2e^{-iπ/3}$.

Of these, the principal root is $2e^{iπ/3}$ but the "main" root is $-2$ because:

$$(-8)^{1/3}=((-2)^3)^{1/3} = -2$$

Not that the "main" root doesn't have to be real, for example, the main square root of $i^2$ is $i$, because $(i^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: We say principal root.

Comment: Can you clarify how "only one can be obtained by replacing the root with exponentiation"? How do you define which root is the result of fractional exponentiation?